# Get week number in year from date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am looking for a query which will return the week number from given date.

What I've already tried is this:

```
select datepart(wk, '2017-02-01')
```

but this returns 5 instead of 6. (february 1st is the 6th week of the year).

(week numbers with red)

[image]

Comment: You need to define what you mean by "week of the year".  The obvious answer is just to add 1 to the value returned by `datepart()`.

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using shorthand with date/time operations - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You probably need to specify the first day of your week with [**`set datefirst`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx):

```
set datefirst 1;
select datepart(week, '2017-02-01');
```

returns `6`

---

Depending on the default language, your `datefirst` might be set to `7`.

```
set datefirst 7;
select datepart(week, '2017-02-01');
```

returns `5`

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/KEPB52852

Comment: Anybody wants to know what is [`set datefirst`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-datefirst-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: The `WEEK` date part overlaps with the previous year (last week of the previous year is the first week of the next year), to avoid that issue is better to go with the [ISO_WEEK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63884844/1657465) answer

Answer (score 25):

You can also consider using 'iso_week' instead of 'week' parameter in 'datepart'. This case you can avoid using 'set datefirst 1', which can be convenient if you can only use a single select.

More details here about 'iso_week': ["ISO 8601 includes the ISO week-date system, a numbering system for weeks. Each week is associated with the year in which Thursday occur"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

You can compare the two like this:

```
SELECT datepart(ISO_WEEK, '2020.01.01') -- Wed
SELECT datepart(WEEK, '2020.01.01') -- Wed
SELECT datepart(ISO_WEEK, '2020.01.05') -- Sun
SELECT datepart(WEEK, '2020.01.05') -- Sun
SELECT datepart(ISO_WEEK, '2020.01.06') -- Mon
SELECT datepart(WEEK, '2020.01.06') -- Mon
```

Note the difference for Sunday, 5 Jan 2020:

```
-----------
1
1
1
2
2
2
```

Comment: Is there a code to get *03* instead of just *3* too?

Comment: @KonradViltersten, use FORMAT as in SELECT FORMAT(DATEPART(WEEK, '2020.01.06'), '00').

Answer (score 7):

You can get the week number from a specific column which contains a date by using:

```
DATEPART(WK, orders.createddate) AS Week,
```

This is taken from the DATEPART functions available below:

```
   DATEPART(YY, orders.createddate) AS Year, 
   DATEPART(QQ, orders.createddate) AS Quarter, 
   DATEPART(WK, orders.createddate) AS Week, 
   DATEPART(DY, orders.createddate) AS dayofYear, 
   DATEPART(MM, orders.createddate) AS Month, 
   DATEPART(DD, orders.createddate) AS Date, 
   DATEPART(hour, orders.createddate) AS Hour, 
   DATEPART(minute, orders.createddate) AS Minute, 
   DATEPART(second, orders.createddate) AS Second, 
   DATEPART(millisecond, orders.createddate) AS Millsecond, 
   DATEPART(microsecond, orders.createddate) AS Microsecond, 
   DATEPART(nanosecond, orders.createddate) AS Nanosecond,
```

Answer (score 2):

For week starting on Monday, without using "set datefirst":

select datepart(iso_week, '2023-03-22')

Because in a SQL view you cannot set datefirst which is a session variable. I found the right documentation:

ISO Week Number
You can also return the ISO week number from a date by using the iso_week argument. ISO weeks start on Mondays and the first week of a year contains January 4 of that year.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is very old, but it might help somebody.
If you mean you want the exact number of week in some given date, then you might use this query:

`SELECT WEEK("2022-05-29"); --> 22`

resource: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_week.asp

Comment: This question is for `sql-server` specific, and `sql-server` doesn't have `week()` function, so you will need to use `datepart()` as other answers.