# Calculating week numbers from custom dates

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have client ids and their dates of login. i want to calculate the week number with respect to their first login date

i am fairly new to sql

Demo output

```
ClientID          Date of login         Week Number
1                 2019-12-20                1
1                 2019-12-21                1
1                 2019-12-21                1 
1                 2019-12-22                1 
1                 2019-12-29                2 
1                 2019-12-29                2
2                 2020-01-27                1 
2                 2020-01-28                1 
2                 2020-02-05                2
2                 2020-02-06                2
2                 2020-02-16                3
```

Comment: Please post your specific `sql` version

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant...)

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42794544/get-week-number-in-year-from-date

Comment: If the first login is on a Saturday, when to you expect week 2 to begin? 7 days after the first login, or on the following Monday?

Comment: next week starts after 7 days of first login

Comment: Get the MIN(login_date) for the user, and get the difference in days between the specific login date and this minimum. Divide by 7 and that should give you a week number relative to the user's first login.

Answer (score 1):

This is very trivial date arithmetic that just requires the `min` `DateOfLogin` for each `ClientID`, which you can find with a windowed function.

Calculate the `datediff` in days between this date and the current `DateOfLogin`, integer divide by `7` (to return no fractional days) and then add `1` to correctly offset the `WeekNum` value:

```
declare @l table(ClientID int, DateOfLogin date);
insert into @l values(1,'2019-12-20'),(1,'2019-12-21'),(1,'2019-12-21'),(1,'2019-12-22'),(1,'2019-12-29'),(1,'2019-12-29'),(2,'2020-01-27'),(2,'2020-01-28'),(2,'2020-02-05'),(2,'2020-02-06'),(2,'2020-02-16');

select ClientID
        ,DateOfLogin
        ,(datediff(day,min(DateOfLogin) over (partition by ClientID),DateOfLogin) / 7) + 1 as WeekNum
from @l;
```

## Output

```
+----------+-------------+---------+
| ClientID | DateOfLogin | WeekNum |
+----------+-------------+---------+
|        1 | 2019-12-20  |       1 |
|        1 | 2019-12-21  |       1 |
|        1 | 2019-12-21  |       1 |
|        1 | 2019-12-22  |       1 |
|        1 | 2019-12-29  |       2 |
|        1 | 2019-12-29  |       2 |
|        2 | 2020-01-27  |       1 |
|        2 | 2020-01-28  |       1 |
|        2 | 2020-02-05  |       2 |
|        2 | 2020-02-06  |       2 |
|        2 | 2020-02-16  |       3 |
+----------+-------------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

This query returns the week number.

`select DATENAME(WW, '2019-12-20')`

This is for MSSQL.

Here might be a solution for you, you'll maybe just have to look at the way you are going to do the insert and maybe optimize it a bit better.

`select 1 AS 'ClientID', '2019-12-20' AS 'LogInDate', 1 AS 'Week'
into #test`

[image]

`insert into #test
select top(1) 1, '2020-02-05', case DATEDIFF(week,'2020-02-05',LogInDate) when 0 then week else Week +1 end from #test where ClientID = 1 order by LogInDate desc`

[image]

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: That is because 2019-12-20 is not week 1.

Comment: OP wants to start numbering weeks at the first login. It has nothing to do with actual week numbers.