# Subtract N from weeknum of current year

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We have table `WeeklyResults`  that looks like this:

```
Year    WeekNum   Value
2021    47        11.0
2021    48        14.0
2021    49        12.0
2021    50        17.0
2021    51        11.8
2021    52        11.3
2021    53        11.1
2022    01        11.5
2022    02        11.5  
2022    03        81.5
```

We have a report with two parameters: Date and WeekNum. The report needs to show the last 6 weeks based on the weeknumber selected.

The issue is that, if user selects Week 2 of 2022, how can I subtract 6 weeks so that I get weeks 50, 51, 52, 53 of 2021 and weeks 1, 2 from 2022?

So, if the user selects *2022* and *Week 02*, it would show the last 6 weeks based on Weeknum 2 of year 2022 (wk50 to Wk02). If user selects 2021 and 52, it would show wk47-52.

Comment: *If* you're just returning the "last 6" weeks, why not use a `TOP (6)` and then `ORDER BY [Year] DESC, WeekNum DESC`?

Comment: I'll edit the question. It's the last 6 weeks based on the weeknum selected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a little `<` and `<=` logic along side `TOP` and `ORDER BY` to achieve this:

```sql
DECLARE @Year int = 2022, 
        @WeekNum int = 3; --Note, if you are storing WeekNum as a (var)char,
                          --your leading zeros imply you are, then define the
                          --variable as a char(2).

SELECT TOP (6)
       [Year],
       WeekNum,
       [Value]
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE ([Year] = @Year AND WeekNum <= @WeekNum)
   OR [Year] < @Year
ORDER BY [Year] DESC,
         WeekNum DESC;
```

Comment: Well, that was simple. Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome, @fdkgfosfskjdlsjdlkfsf . If it answers the question, please do consider marking it as the solution so that future readers know the answer was helpful. Thanks. (Some of your other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4191466/fdkgfosfskjdlsjdlkfsf?tab=questions) could do with the same treatment.)

Comment: I note that despite the `OR` this can still be satisfied with two unioned index seeks https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=255c2b0ce98051e0f1058f45340fdb79 (difficult to spot because they go all the way into the storage engine)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Year       int         =   2022
    ,   @WeekNum    varchar(02) =   '02'
;

WITH FinalTable AS
    (
        SELECT  TOP 6 *
        FROM    WeeklyResults
        ORDER BY LTRIM(Year) + WeekNum DESC
    )

SELECT *
FROM    FinalTable  
ORDER BY Year, WeekNum
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option that doesn't involve an ORDER BY. Using [DATEPART](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) you can determine the final week of the prior year and subtract the number of weeks to get the records needed.

You may need to adjust what day is the first day of the week for your count. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42794544/get-week-number-in-year-from-date) for more info on that.

```
DECLARE
    @Year INT = 2022
    , @WeekNum INT = 3;

SELECT
    *
FROM
    WeeklyResults
WHERE
    Year = @Year
    AND WeekNum <= @WeekNum
    OR
        (
            @WeekNum < 6
            AND Year = @Year - 1
            AND WeekNum > DATEPART (WEEK, CONCAT ('12/31/', @Year - 1)) - @WeekNum
        );
```