# Add week number column in query results from existing date column

Tags: sql, sql-server

The current query is shown below and I am struggling with trying to add a column to my results query, where it converts the PRODUCTION_DATE into fiscal week.

```
SELECT        
    ORDER_QTY, SKU, INVOICE_NUMBER, CUSTOMER_NUMBER, ROUTE, 
    ALLOCATED_QTY, SHORTED_QTY, PRODUCTION_DATE
FROM          
    [DATEBASE_NAME].[XYZ].[ORDERS]
WHERE 
    [PRODUCTION_DATE] >= DATEADD(day, -300, GETDATE())  
    AND [PRODUCTION_DATE] <= GETDATE()
```

I believe `DATEPART` is part of the function, I just don't know how to execute. End goal would be a column in the results that just returns the fiscal week along with all other data. The little query above returns my data proper now, I am just trying to get that column in.

Thanks for looking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get week number in year from date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42794544/get-week-number-in-year-from-date)

Comment: How do you define your fiscal weeks? Are you sure they correspond with `datepart` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have already mentioned about `DATEPART`;

(And you were almost there !!)

Here is the modified query

```
SELECT        
    ORDER_QTY, SKU, INVOICE_NUMBER, CUSTOMER_NUMBER, ROUTE, 
    ALLOCATED_QTY, SHORTED_QTY, PRODUCTION_DATE,
    DATEPART(wk, PRODUCTION_DATE) AS FISCAL_WEEK
FROM          
    [DATEBASE_NAME].[XYZ].[ORDERS]
WHERE 
    [PRODUCTION_DATE] >= DATEADD(day, -300, GETDATE())  
    AND [PRODUCTION_DATE] <= GETDATE();
```